# How do I install 3.0 TB HDD

Tags: hard-drive

I just bought 3.0 TB Western Digital Internal Hard Disk.

I put it in the PC & it was detected as 2.0 TB HDD in Disk Management.

It also asked me to initialize the disk either as MBR or GPT Partition.

I am using Dell T-7500 Workstation with Windows 7 (64 bit)

Can you please help me with following questions:

1. What should I do to get full 3.0 TB Space then rather 2.0 it shows now
2. SHould I initialize it first if I want to install Win-7 on it OR just Pop the Win-7 DVD & start installing it & it will guide me thru the rest of the procedure & help me select MBR or GPT then?
3. What should I do if I just want to have Large 3.0 TB single partition? Should I initialize it & which one, MBR or GPT ?
4. What should I do in case I initialize it either as GPT or MBR & don't get full 3.0 TB of space?

Comment: 1. Get a newer BIOS. 2. Yes. 3. GPT. 4. Try again.

Answer (score 1):

Read this link from [community.dell.com](http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/extras/w/wiki/2837.aspx).  It explains the ins and outs of using 3TB disks on Dell hardware, with various BIOS versions and operating systems.

Comment: To summarize what the link says: BIOS can only support up to 2TB you must switch to UEFI mode to enable > 2TB support. If your mother board does not support UEFI, you have no way to use > 2TB hard drives.

Comment: Thank You. I read the article. But didn;t understand much as it was talking about older Dell systems. How do I find out if my motherboard supports UEFI ? Also if I partition it as GPT, will that yield 3 TB instead of 2 TB it shows now ?